# How to allow data quotas using nDPI netfiltering

Tags: iptables, quota, traffic-filtering

I am trying to allow a certain data quota for a user using nDPI netfiltering.

This is the command I used for checking it.

`iptables -A INPUT -m ndpi --quota 2048 -j DROP`

Result is 
**`iptables v1.6.0: unknown option "--quota"`**

As I read in this [manual page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) for iptables 1.4.20 . It can be done.

What would be the correct syntax for this?

I am totally newby for this field. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from this [forum](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-byte-count-and-quota-4175590847/).

```
iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT ! -s 192.168.X.Y -m quota --quota 1024000 -j ACCEPT -c 0 0

iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT ! -s 192.168.X.Y -j DROP
```

Replace 192.168.X.Y with your router. This is actually optional. **! -s 192.168.X.Y** ignores the packets receiving from your router which is 192.168.X.Y.

You can also check whether rules are applied by using this command.

```
iptables -vnL
```

If they applied properly you should get something like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   18  1900 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  *      !192.168.10.1         0.0.0.0/0            quota: 10485760 bytes
    0     0 DROP       all  --  wlan0  *      !192.168.10.1         0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 332 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```